# I don't have result for my fullcalendar tooltip

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, tooltip, primeng

I'm setting tooltips on events with fullcalendar from primeng.
When i run my code, i see my tooltip initialized into the web console but i can't see it when i passed my mouse over an event.

I am developing with Typescript, [Primeng 7.0.5](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fullcalendar), Angular 6.
I am using the fullcalendar v4.0 from PrimeNg and i follow the tooltip example which is in the [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender) page.

There is my code:

loan.component.ts

```
    eventRender: function(info) {
                 let tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                 title: 'test',
                 placement: 'top',
                 trigger: 'hover',
                 container: 'body'
                 });
                 console.log(tooltip);
             }
```

loan.component.html

```
<div id="calendar" class="row col-xl-12">        
    <p-fullCalendar [events]="events" [options]="options"></p-fullCalendar>
</div>
```

the result into my console :

```
    Tooltip {show: ƒ, hide: ƒ, dispose: ƒ, toggle: ƒ, updateTitleContent: ƒ, …}
        dispose: ƒ ()
        hide: ƒ ()
        options: {container: "body", delay: 0, html: false, placement: "top", 
        title: "test", …}
        reference: a.fc-day-grid-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.fc-not-start.fc-end
        show: ƒ ()
        toggle: ƒ ()
        updateTitleContent: ƒ (title)
        _events: (2) [{…}, {…}]
        _isOpen: false
        _popperOptions: {}
        _setTooltipNodeEvent: ƒ (evt, reference, delay, options)
        __proto__: Object
```

For the moment it is initialized but when my mouse is on an event, nothing append

Did you ever had a problem like this ?

Comment: any errors in your console? Did you include tooltip.js in your page?

Comment: I haven't any error into my console, i implemented Tooltip in my loan.component.ts file like this: import Tooltip from 'tooltip.js';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes from the CSS !

I don't know why but the tooltip have to change its opacity when i hover it but it don't take effect.
I changed manually the opacity value and it's fonctionnal.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how?

Comment: i changed the opacity of the tooltip from 0 to 10 into my tooltip.scss

Comment: I had the same problem and I got it working now by setting a .tooltip { opacity: 1; } in my css file, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem and even setting css didn't work for me. I had to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in my component decorator.

Firstly in my components's css file. I have added

```
.tooltip{
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Then in my component's ts file I have added

```
@Component({                 
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And my event render function is

```
eventRender(info) {    
    let tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
    title: '<h6>test</h6>',
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: 'body',
    html: true
    });
}
```

Note: I am using Augular version `8.2` and Full-Calendar version `4.3`